# Java Key Listener doesn't work

Tags: java

today i tried to include a KeyListener into my first java problem.
I searched on multiple sites for a solution, but sadly didn't found one.

Maybe someone of you guys, could have a look at it.

```
    public class AL extends KeyAdapter {
        public AL() {

        }

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            key = e.getKeyCode();

            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
                System.out.println("Left Button pressed");
            }
        }
    }
```

Full code:
http://pastebin.com/FfdHymFp

Comment: This has been a part of Java since JDK 1.0.  Sadly, the error is on your end.  Please post the offending code here; I don't click on links that take me outside SO>

Comment: cant post full code here, cuz limit

Comment: There's a problem right there: Too much code.  Create a small, self-contained, executable example to demonstrate your issue.  It might help you figure out how to decompose your god class.

Comment: hi you should have frame then include your panel , it is better to listen from the frame

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your `KeyListener` to a `Component` using the method `addKeyListener(KeyListener)` otherwise it cannot work.

Please have a look to [this doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html)